# Easiest way to find spatial differences between Polyline shapefiles

Tags: arcgis-desktop, line, comparison, erase

I run into this problem a lot. I have two polyline's and I need to test for Spatial differences in them. Usually I use Erase and I have my answer, but on this PC I now only have access to ArcGIS Basic license.

I have found ways to do this by creating a temporary copy of the files and doing some editing, but there has to be a better way!

Comment: Did you look at the Feature Compare tool?

Comment: Are you able to provide a diagram/link for what you mean by "spatial difference"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could export the nodes from each polyline and calculate the spatial different for each node to the corresponding node.  This would give you numbers that you could then do a range of stats on.